# LightSpeed cast a dynamic model to strong typed inside Razor template

Tags: c#, razor, lightspeed

I need some help with casting model in template with LightSpeed.

When I used Entity Framework everything was ok, but with LS i can say just:

```
@inherits NancyRazorViewBase<dynamic>
@var Projects = Model.Projects // It's a collection of Project Enitities 
@foreach(MyAssemblyNamespace.Models.Project project in Projects) {
    // ...
}
```

Because I'll receive error:

```
[CS0012] Line: 18 Column: 10 - The type 'Mindscape.LightSpeed.Entity`1' is defined 
in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 
'Mindscape.LightSpeed, Version=5.0.2597.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=360c8f37b466ebb2'. (show)
```

Comment: And did you add a reference to this assembly?

Comment: Inside Web.config:


      <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <pages pageBaseType="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase`1[[System.Object]]">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Mindscape.LightSpeed, Version=5.0.2597.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360c8f37b466ebb2" /> 
          </assemblies>

Comment: and also inside Visual Studio gui i have one